# How to repeatedly perform glm over multiple dependent variables after mice?

Tags: r, glm, r-mice

I have a data frame, `nrow=4312, ncol=105`, with which I performed multiple imputations using `mice`:

```
imp <- mice(data, m=20, maxit=10, method=meth, predictorMatrix=pred2, visitSequence=vis)
```

Now, I need to perform multiple logistic regressions repeatedly and separately with 40 different dependent variables and extract particular values into different data frame. The example for one such regression and value extraction being:

```
fit.HDP <- with(imp, glm(HDP ~ P0 + BMI + WtChange + MATAGE, family=binomial, subset=(P1==1)))
est.HDP <- pool(fit.HDP)
HDP <- summary(est.HDP)

HDP.OR <- exp(HDP[2,1])
HDP.95CI <- exp(HDP[2,c(6,7)])
HDP.pvalue <- HDP[2,5]
```

1. How can I do this faster than writing this out 40 times over for each variable?
2. Is it possible to do it using a for loop?

Thank you for all help!

Comment: take a look at `?update`. Also look at the broom package for obtaining your estimates and confidence intervals.

Comment: Do a loop and use `update.formula()` to modify the dependent variable in each iteration of the loop.

Comment: In your example, what is a variable that changes (is it `P0` )?

Comment: Sorry, forgot that key detail...`HDP` changes

Comment: `update.formula` worked with both `lapply` and for loop...nice to know more than one way at a problem, thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
form <- as.formula("~ P0 + BMI + WtChange + MATAGE")
listOfGlms<-lapply(vectorOfDependentVariables, function(x) {
        lm(substitute(update.formula(form, i ~ .), list(i = as.name(x))), family=binomial, subset=(P1==1))
        })
```

The `lapply` can of course also be replaced by a for loop.

Answer (score 1):

### Update with purrr package, included in the tidyverse

You can now write the correct answer by @Prolix with purrr:map, which makes it a little more intuitive to read, like this:

```
library(tidyverse)

independent.variables.formula <- "~ P0 + BMI + WtChange + MATAGE"
dependent.variables <- c("HDP", "DV2", "DV3")

models.list <- map(dependent.variables, function(DV) {

  paste(DV, independent.variables.formula) %>% 
    as.formula %>% 
    lm(family=binomial, subset=(P1==1))
})
```